# Как стилизовать таблицу?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно стилизовать таблицу таким образом. Нужно некоторые строки объединять (группировать и выделять таким вот образом.

Искал в гугле, задавал вопрос в chat gpt) не нашел ответа(

Comment: Гуглите `rowspan`, `colspan`, `border-collapse`, `border`. Ну а задать цвета думаю проблем не должно быть.

Comment: Гридами в общем div, хотя и таблицей должно получиться

Comment: Создать три таблицы))

Comment: Таблица какая - статичная, динамическая, интерактивная?

Comment: Как вариант - создать четыре класса `начало группы`, `внутри группы`, `окончание группы`, и `единственный элемент`. Правильно присвоить соответствующие классы строкам таблицы.

Comment: @ksa, автор _"задавал вопрос в chat gpt"_, а с нами общаться не желает видимо :(

Comment: @UModeL, ну это его выбор... :-D

Comment: @UModeL Динамическая

Comment: Как я уже писал нужно создать три таблицы. Они же делятся по определённому параметру на три группы? Ну так вот пусть и создают на каждый параметр по таблице. Либо тупо div-ами сделать и стилизовать через grid. А при разделении нужно, чтобы добавлял в этот ряд класс "delimiter" например и по нему уже делать эти отступы и border-radius-ы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такая таблица на grid

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
div {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table {
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #B5D6E4;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thead, .tRow {
  display: grid;
}
.thead {
  grid-template-columns: 50px 200px 1fr;
  background-color: #B5D6E4;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.thead > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
.thead > div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.tRow {
  grid-template-columns: 45px 200px 1fr;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.tRow:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.tRow > div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.tRow > div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.delimiter {
  background-color: #1D51D6;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="num">ID</div>
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="desc">Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="delimiter">
    <div class="tRow">
      <div class="num">12</div>
      <div class="name">Some Name</div>
      <div class="desc">Some Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tRow">
      <div class="num">13</div>
      <div class="name">Some Name</div>
      <div class="desc">Some Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tRow">
      <div class="num">14</div>
      <div class="name">Some Name</div>
      <div class="desc">Some Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="delimiter">
    <div class="tRow">
      <div class="num">15</div>
      <div class="name">Some Name</div>
      <div class="desc">Some Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="delimiter">
    <div class="tRow">
      <div class="num">16</div>
      <div class="name">Some Name</div>
      <div class="desc">Some Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```